# Bayesian Estimation: Bernoulli and Quadratic Loss Function

Tags: self-study, bayesian, loss-functions, mse, minimax

I am trying to understand a solution to this problem (I am a very beginner in Bayesian statistics) and I am terribly confused so I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me how exactly this risk function was obtained. I would also appreciate any pointers/advice on the literature where I can encounter similar problems and a good explanation of the core concepts:
$$ X_{1}, . . . X_{n} $$ is Bernoulli with unknown parameter $ \theta_{0} $

$$ \hat\theta_{1} = \bar X  $$

$$\hat\theta_{2}=\dfrac{n\bar X + a}{n + c}$$
and $ a<c $

The risk for $ \hat\theta_{1} $ is
$$R\left(\hat\theta_{1},\theta_{0}\right) = \frac{1}{n}\theta_{0}(1 - \theta_{0}) $$

The risk for $\hat\theta_{2} $ is
$$R\left(\hat\theta_{2},\theta_{0}\right) = \frac{1}{(c+n)^2}[(a -\theta_{0}c)^2+n\theta_{0}(1-\theta_{0})] $$

So my problem is, I think I understand how the bias was derived but I do not really understand why the variance is multiplied by n , i.e. $n\theta_{0}(1-\theta_{0})$? Actually, when I square the Bias, I do not understand what happens to $ n{E}[\bar X]  $ and $ - \theta_{0} $ when I plug $\hat\theta_{2}$ in $ ({E}(\hat\theta) - \theta_{0})^2 $ . Are they equal? If so, why are they equal?

And I am also confused by this result for $$ 
\hat\theta_{1} = \frac{n\bar{X}+\sqrt{n}/2}{n + \sqrt{n}} $$ 
which corresponds to  $$ a= \sqrt{n}/2 \text{ and } c = \sqrt{n} $$
and which has a risk equal to
 $$ R(\hat\theta_{1},\theta_0) = \frac{1}{4n} \frac{n^2}{(n + \sqrt{n})^2} $$

When I plug in these values in $R\left(\hat\theta_{2},\theta_{0}\right)$, I do not understand where **$n^2$** in the numerator and $4n$ in the denominator come from.

Thank you in advance for any advice/recommendations.

Comment: These issues are covered in standard Bayesian decision textbooks like [Berger's (1985)](http://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/0387960988/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1642&creative=19458&creativeASIN=0387960988&linkCode=as2&tag=xianblog-21&linkId=U5L5WGH5BQT2WXCP) or [mine](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0387715983?ie=UTF8&tag=chrprobboo-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=0387715983).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The risk for $\hat\theta_{2} $ is
\begin{align*}
R(\hat\theta_{2},\theta_{0}) &= \mathbb{E}_{\theta_0}\left[ (\hat\theta_2(X)-\theta_0)^2 \right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}_{\theta_0}\left[ \left(\frac{n\bar{X}+a}{n+c} - \theta_0\right)^2 
\right] \\
&= \left(\frac{n\mathbb{E}_{\theta_0}[\bar{X}]+a}{n+c} - \theta_0\right)^2 + \text{var}_{\theta_0}\left(\frac{n}{(n+c)}\,\bar{X}\right)\\
&= \left(\frac{n\theta_0+a}{n+c} - \theta_0\right)^2 + \frac{n^2}{(n+c)^2}\,\text{var}_{\theta_0}(\bar{X})\\
&= \left(\frac{a-c\theta_0}{n+c}\right)^2 + \frac{n^2}{(n+c)^2}\,\frac{\theta_0(1-\theta_0)}{n}\\
&= \frac{1}{(c+n)^2}[(a -\theta_{0}c)^2+n\theta_{0}(1-\theta_{0})] 
\end{align*}

So you get the squared bias plus the variance of the Bayes estimator, which is the variance of the sample average multiplied by the square of the coefficient.

The second part follows from using
$$ a= \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{n} \ \text{ and }\  c = \sqrt{n} $$
in the above general formula and expanding the two squared quantities:
\begin{align*}
 \frac{1}{(\sqrt{n}+n)^2}&[\{(1/2)\sqrt{n} -\theta_{0}\sqrt{n}\}^2+n\theta_{0}(1-\theta_{0})] \\
&= \frac{n}{(\sqrt{n}+n)^2}\left[
\frac{1}{4} -\theta_0+\theta_0^2+\theta_0-\theta_0^2
\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{4(1+\sqrt{n})^2}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you so much!It was incredibly helpful!I have 1 question: when I add the variance of the Bayes estimator, i.e. $$ + \text{var}_{\theta_0}\left(\frac{n}{(n+c)}\,\bar{X}\right) $$ why do I only multiply it by $$ \frac{n}{(n+c)}\,\bar{X} $$ , i.e. not by $$ \frac{n + a}{(n+c)}\,\bar{X} $$ what happens to $ a $ ?

Comment: Your estimator is $$\dfrac{n\bar{X}+a}{n+c}=\dfrac{n\bar{X}}{n+c}+\dfrac{a}{n+c}$$ and the second term is a constant.

Comment: that makes sense!Thank you!And so since the Variance of a constant is zero, I can just get rid of $$\frac{a}{n + c}$$ in $$ {var}_{\theta_0}\left(\frac{n}{(n+c)}\,\bar{X}\right) $$ ,right?

Comment: @Jen: yes, indeed $var(X+a)=var(X)$ when $a$ is a constant. Don't forget to tick the answer if you think it solves the issue!

Comment: just ticked it and thank you so much for your help!I will definitely check out your book and Berger and again, this has been incredibly helpful and I've been struggling to understand it for so long and your thorough explanation has made everything crystal clear, I appreciate it immensely!